# Unique question - Alien Invasion - Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, google-colaboratory

I'm creating Alien Invasions from Chapter 12 in *Python Crash Course*. It's saying:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-0a7dc30aa722> in <module>()
     22 if __name__ == "__main__":
     23   # Make a game instance, and run the game.
---> 24   ai = AlienInvasion()
     25   ai.run_game()

<ipython-input-13-0a7dc30aa722> in __init__(self)
      5     """initialize the game, and create game resources."""
      6     pygame.init()
----> 7     self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
      8     pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
      9 

error: No available video device
```

Here's the code:

```
import pygame

class AlienInvasion:
  """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

  def __init__(self):
    """initialize the game, and create game resources."""
    pygame.init()
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

  def run_game(self):
    """Start the main loop for the game"""

    while True:
    #Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
      for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          sys.exit()

    #Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Make a game instance, and run the game.
  ai = AlienInvasion()
  ai.run_game()
```

([Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TDUoxoBnxa77_0hxI1vv_h638rb1yaRN?usp=sharing))

Comment: What's a better way to share it here? Or is the link that I posted above the best way? The code seems to long to paste here. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's a good idea to post as much relevant information in your post/question as you can. For example, you said "I did something wrong and can't figure it out". What makes you say that? Is there an error message? If so, what is the error? Make it as easy as possible for other people to want to help you.

Comment: Thank you!
It's saying:
error                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-0a7dc30aa722> in <module>()
     22 if __name__ == "__main__":
     23   # Make a game instance, and run the game.
---> 24   ai = AlienInvasion()
     25   ai.run_game()

<ipython-input-13-0a7dc30aa722> in __init__(self)
      5     """initialize the game, and create game resources."""
      6     pygame.init()
----> 7     self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
      8     pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
     

error: No available video device

Comment: My hunch is that there is simply no way for `pygame` to function properly within a jupyter notebook, since you're basically interpreting python within a web application. You'll have to run the code locally.